# Testing that beforeUpdate or beforeInsert are fired in Grails with Spock

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, beforeupdate

I'm new in Grails and I'm doing some tests but although beforeUpdate and beforeInsert are called in development, my tests say they aren't, what I'm doing wrong?

I'm mocking Cicle and Measurement so I think that when the method save is called, the beforeUpdate or beforeInsert are triggered, but when I run the tests grails answers back saing "Too few invocations for: 1 * cicle.updateCicleValue()   (0 invocations)"

So am I using the "when" incorrectly? or save doesn't trigger beforeUpdate and beforeInsert in mock objects?

Please help :)

Cicle.goovy

```
class Cicle {

String machine
double cicleValue

static hasMany = [measurements:Measurement]

def beforeInsert(){
    if (measurements != null) updateCicleValue()
}

def beforeUpdate(){
    if (measurements != null) updateCicleValue()
}

public void updateCicleValue(){

    double sumCicleValue = 0

    measurements.each{ measurement ->
        sumCicleValue += measurement.cicleValue
    }

    cicleValue = sumCicleValue / measurements.size()
}   
}
```

CicleSepc.groovy

```
@TestFor(Cicle)
@Mock([Cicle, Measurement])
class CicleSpec extends Specification {

Measurement mea1    
Measurement mea2    
Cicle cicle


def setup() {
    mea1 = new Measurement(machine: "2-12", cicleValue: 34600)      
    mea2 = new Measurement(machine: "2-12", cicleValue: 17280)      
    cicle = new Cicle(machine: "2-12")

    cicle.addToMeasurements(mea1)
    cicle.addToMeasurements(mea2)       
}

def cleanup() {
}

void "Test updateCicleValue is triggered"(){

    when: "Saving..."
    cicle.save(flush:true)

    then: "updateCicleValue is called once"
    1 * cicle.updateCicleValue()
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unit spec is not a good place for testing event hooks. Try with an integration spec.

Comment: why isn't it? is this the reason it doesn't work? how can you tell its a unit spec?

Comment: Yes this is the reason it does not work. Unit test environment is deprived of the full persistent environment, hence those events has to be tested in integration or functional test environments.

Comment: I'm testing the same thing without the @Mock in integration test and I'm still getting the same problem: Too few invocations for: 1 * cicle.updateCalculations()   (0 invocations)

Comment: Since you are not mocking anything in the integration test, checking cardinality of interactions will not work. What you can actually test is that the value of `circleValue` has updated before insert. Look out my answer for a sample test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//Integration Spec
import grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

class AuthorIntSpec extends IntegrationSpec {

    void "test something"() {
        given:
           def author

        when:
            Author.withNewSession {
                author = new Author(name: 'blah').save(flush: true)
            }

        then:
            author.name == 'foo'
    }
}

//Author
class Author {
    String name

    def beforeInsert() {
        this.name = 'foo'
    }
}
```

Also note, to use `withNewSession`in events if you end up persisting any entity although above simple test would pass without specifying `withNewSesion` (mentioned for brevity).

In your use case, there is no mocking involved so testing an interaction is not possible afaik, but you can assert that the value of `circleValue` has updated after insert (flush), which in turn tests that `beforeInsert` event is fired appropriately.